# Bug in adjustl in gfortran when applied to an allocatable string

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I am modifying a program developed using ifort to work with gfortran as well, and I am running into an issue with calling `adjustl` on an allocatable string. The following program will produce unexpected output when compiled with gfortran:

```
program compilercheck
    implicit none
    character(len=:), allocatable :: string

    string = " Hi" !Note leading space
    string = adjustl(string(2:))

    if(string == "Hi") then
        write(*,*) "You compiled with ifort"
    else
        write(*,*) "You compiled with gfortran"
    endif
end program compilercheck
```

Instead of `string` becoming "Hi" as expected (and when compiling with ifort) it ends up as "H". The bug can be worked around by changing the call to `adjustl(...)` into `adjustl(trim(...))`, but it seems very strange that that would affect the result (no trailing spaces). Is there a bug in gfortran or is the code doing something beyond the fortran specifications that ifort allows? I am using gfortran version 7.5.0 for reference.

Comment: Definitely a bug in gfortran and quite likely a known one. Try a more recent version. The current one is 10.

Comment: Works with gfortran 10.0.1 20200225 (experimental) on my laptop, but not with 6, 7 or 8.

Comment: Indeed, downloading and using gfortran 9 instead solves the issue. Unfortunately gfortran 9 can not compile other parts of the code that gfortran 7 can, but that is a separate issue from this one. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you reported the issues that have with gfortran 9 to the gfortran contributors?

Answer (score 1):

It is sad to see that the bug is apparently not reported.
Here is a workaround wrapper, for those, who stuck with gfrotran-8 or below. Also it doesn't require `trim()`.

```
  function adjustlFIX(str) result(res)
   character(len=*), intent(in) :: str
   character(:),allocatable :: res
   res = adjustl(str)
  end function adjustlFIX
```

Comment: There is not much point reporting it when it was fixed years ago. These versions of gfortran like 7 or 8 are no longer supported. Supported are 10, 11 and 12. Besides, there was no lack of similar reports at the time.